# Recommended neighborhood for young U.S. couple moving to Stockholm?

Tags: sweden, housing

My wife and I will be moving to Stockholm for my job in May. We're currently working with a relocation firm to procure housing (likely small - i.e., 1BR apartment). For a young couple (i.e., 30) with no children, what neighborhood would you recommend in the inner city? We're looking for access to parks, potential water views, fun restaurants, shops, and bars.

Comment: Do you speak any Swedish? Although most speak English, I have heard they are much more accepting of foreign people who attempt to use the native tongue.

Comment: Hi David and welcome to expats.se :) I think your question is not good for our format: it's opinion-based and also not a really expat question

Comment: @TimSeguine While in any country the effort to learn the local language will be rewarding, to say "much more accepting" overreaches. Swedes are happy to converse in their (usually excellent) English with foreigners. When I lived there I spoke English the majority of the time and found absolutely no lack of acceptance. My halting attempts at Swedish could certainly brighten an interaction, but there were no dark clouds over the English-only conversations, and I left behind many new friends there.

Comment: @JonathanVanMatre okay, I tend to use exaggerated language. If it sounds too extreme, then imagine I worded it less strongly. Your experience trumps my hearsay in any case.

Comment: @TimSeguine All good, my friend. :) I just didn't want our young couple here to fear they will find an icy welcome when they first arrive. Swedes are warmer than their stereotype lets on.

Answer (score 2):

I can highly recommend looking at Solna, it's a great neighborhood which is very near to downtown and quick to commute. It's very green and has nice restaurants and shops. Apartment prices in Solna are also not nearly as inflated as other parts of town.

Realistically, as an expat you'll have a very difficult time finding a rental apartment in Stockholm, so buying a flat is probably your best bet (if you can afford to do so). The process is not as scary as it sounds, but also is more involved than I care to go into for this answer. :) At any rate, [hemnet](http://hemnet.se/) is your friend, be sure to spend sufficient time researching the different neighborhoods.

Also, if you are working downtown, you should search for flats which are on one of Stockholms metro lines (tunnelbana). The commuter trains (pendeltåg) run much less frequently, stop running sooner at night, and are more prone to disruptions during winter.